# how to use client.get_all_emojis() discord.py

Tags: discord.py

i try:

```
discord.utils.get(client.get_all_emojis(), id=469334117020991508)
```

but this return none every time

I would like to get the url custom emoji from chat text.

Comment: If you're using discord.py 0.16, then all ids are strings.  Try `discord.utils.get(client.get_all_emojis(), id="469334117020991508")`

Answer (score 1):

Your code *should* work - you're using `get_all_emojis()` correctly. The most likely reason that it is returning `None` is that there is no emoji with that id. Try something like `print(list(client.get_all_emojis()))` and see if there is actually an entry with that id.