# Why client.emojis, newer version of client.get_all_emojis() returns empy list when using Discord's Python API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982339/8565438), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982433/8565438), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51475407/8565438) & [this](https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/16b581c1cad3a6e02c6d1b59379dabc7), I expected `client.get_all_emojis()` to work in my Discord chat bot:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio
import os

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'send emoji':
        await message.channel.send(client.get_all_emojis()[0])

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I expected `client.get_all_emojis()` to be a list, & wanted the bot to send the first element of that list. I get however:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/ps738/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> line 312, in _run_event
>
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                         > File "bot5.py", line 15, in on_message
>
> await message.channel.send(client.get_all_emojis()[0])                                                                                            > AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_all_emojis'

Main point: **'Client' object has no attribute 'get_all_emojis'**.

How can I fix this?

---

**ADD**

Based on [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh)'s comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982339/8565438) & [this source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.emojis) of [PrimeEpoch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13794067/primeepoch)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544447/8565438) to my question, I tried replacing `client.get_all_emojis()[0]` with `client.emojis[0]`. Now it says: `IndexError: list index out of range`, so probably an empty list was returned, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're using the rewrite version of discord.py, from what I found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful), you should use client.emojis

Comment: Good source! The problem is that it seems to return an empty list (see ADD in OP)

Comment: @zabop Ah yeah looks like you'll need to add some emojis into your server, I believe it only works for emojis specific to your server and not the standard ones.

Comment: Oh ok. Would you be able to show how to send the standard ones? :)

Comment: Those are just standard unicode emojis, I think you might be interested in the emoji module at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-emojis

Alternatively, you can get the specific unicode emoji you want and just paste it into your code. You can make discord send the unicode emoji by putting a backslash before sending with a regular user, so "\:joy: " will come out as , which you can copy straight into your code.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link (oops) https://pypi.org/project/emoji/